# What is better to use in namedParameterJdbcTemplate parameters

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, java-8

All variants are works, question is about optimization.

single parameter:

```
namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, Collections.singletonMap("id", id), new ClientMapper())
```

or

```
namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new MapSqlParameterSource("id", id), new ClientMapper());
```

multiple parameters:

```
namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(
        sql, 
        new MapSqlParameterSource("view", view)
                .addValue("id", id)
);
```

or

```
namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(sql, new HashMap<String, Object>() {
    {
        put("view", view);
        put("id", id);
    }
});
```

Comment: Don’t use that double-curly-brace anti-pattern. You are creating an entire subclass of `HashMap` just to save a few characters in source code. And since it is an inner class, that instance you’ve created holds a reference to the object of the enclosing class which can cause quite surprising memory leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always look at the source code :

```
@Override
public int update(String sql, Map<String, ?> paramMap) throws DataAccessException {
    return update(sql, new MapSqlParameterSource(paramMap));
}
```

So, using one over another shouldn't matter :)

Comment: That suggests that `update` is overloaded and using a `MapSqlParameterSource` in the first place would directly invoke the other `update` method without another wrapping of the parameter, wouldn’t it?

Comment: @Holger - Well. C2 compiler might inline this as well since these are just method calls

Comment: A method call and a temporary hash map. Surely, the optimizer can elide that, but we shouldn’t delegate everything to the optimizer when the choices are equivalent in source code size and complexity or, like in this case, the potentially more efficient variant is also the cleaner one, comparing the `new MapSqlParameterSource("view", view).addValue("id", id)` expression with the double-curly-brace anonymous inner class subclass of `HashMap` anti-pattern of the second variant.

Comment: Why is the second option an antipattern?

Comment: See [the comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35721367/what-is-better-to-use-in-namedparameterjdbctemplate-parameters/35721427?noredirect=1#comment59117899_35721367)

Comment: @Holger - Well, that applies to all anonymous subclasses :) . But you are right

Comment: Not always. There is the recommendation of subclassing only when you are really going to extend or alter the behavior (related to the “prefer composition over inheritance rule”). For an anonymous listener, everything’s fine. It adds behavior (implements the notification method) and usually accesses the members of the captured outer instance for that. Subclassing a `Hashmap` just for adding some initial values (saving the `varName.` per `put` invocation) is a different story. What makes it worse is when developers using the “cool {{}} trick to save typing” aren’t aware that they’re subclassing.

Comment: @Holger - yes. You are right :)